# angularjs namespace in $stateProvider.state

Tags: angularjs

i have following states in my app

```
 .state('app.users', {
              url: '/Users',
              title: 'Users',
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('User/Index')
          })
          .state('app.users.create', {
              url: '/Create',
              title: 'Users',
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('User/Create')
          })
```

when i link to above state using ui-sref it doesn't load related view , the state change as i can see url change , to get this working i changed the 'app.users.create' to  'app.UsersCreate' as bellow

```
      .state('app.UsersCreate', {
          url: '/Users/Create',
          title: 'Users',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('User/Create')
      })
```

it works , but  when app grow it is hard to manage the state , what is wrong with the first code block ? how can i make 'app.users.create'  work ?

thank you .

Comment: app.users.create is a sub-state of app.users, but you don't want that. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a ui-view declared inside the template for /Users?

Child states usually load in the ui-view inside the parent state. If you don't have this then  need something like the following to tell UI Router to load the child state in the same root level ui-view.

```
  .state('app.users.create', {
          url: '/Create',
          title: 'Users',
          views : { '@' : {
                              templateUrl: helper.basepath('User/Create')
                          }
                  }
        );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , yes I want to load child state in same root level ui-view . I tried your code . the state changes and I see from network tab the reponse but I doesn't show or replace in root level . nothing is shown .